# SSRS parameter default view

Tags: drop-down-menu, reporting-services, parameters, report

When I have to choose the value of parameter from drop-down box, it shows me "Select a value" by default. But I have "years" in this drop-down box. Can I rename "Select a value" to "Select a year" somehow?

Comment: 1. Are your "Available Values" being derived from a Dataset or Manually Configured?
2. Presumably you don't want any Default Value chosen for when the report is first run? And it is not a multi-value parameter?

Comment: 1. Manually. 2. don`t want 3. it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your "Available Values" add an option with the Label "Select a Year" and a Dummy Value.
2. Then in the "Default Values" specify the value you specified in Step 1.

Now when the report loads it should load with "Select a Year" populated.

Comment: But this Value is displayed in drop-down list.

Comment: Is the "Select a Value" not displayed in the drop-down list also?

Comment: Oh, Its really dusplayed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in SSRS load design view, on the left hand side where you have a folder structure expand Parameters. You should see your years parameter there.

Right click on it --> Properties.

On the general section, there is a textfield for prompt.

Comment: This does not specifically change the "Select a Value" text in the dropdown, but changes the prompt next to the dropdown box. That said the prompt should be sufficient to indicate the requirements.